# Getting error for Get request in Rest Assured

Tags: java, rest, groovy, rest-assured

i am new to RestAssured api testing,i'm getting exception while running my basic code.i have added all the required jars and tried all the suggestions available in the online but still not able to find solution for this. please somebody help me in this
. Thanks in advance.

### code

```
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import io.restassured.RestAssured;
import io.restassured.response.Response;

public class Test1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        URL url=new URL("http://dummy.restapiexample.com/");
        Response resp=RestAssured.get(url);
        int status=resp.getStatusCode();
        String respText=resp.getBody().toString();
        System.out.println(respText+"      "+status);
    }

}
```

### Exception log

```
Exception in thread "main" groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static io.restassured.internal.http.URIBuilder.convertToURI() is applicable for argument types: (String) values: [http://dummy.restapiexample.com/]
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeStaticMissingMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1568)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeStaticMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1554)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.StaticMetaClassSite.call(StaticMetaClassSite.java:50)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:139)
    at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.generateRequestUriForLogging(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:1103)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:107)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:323)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1262)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1029)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:816)
    at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.invokeMethod(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.call(PogoInterceptableSite.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.callCurrent(PogoInterceptableSite.java:55)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:51)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:171)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:194)
    at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.newFilterContext(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:1064)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:107)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:323)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1262)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1029)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:816)
    at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.invokeMethod(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.call(PogoInterceptableSite.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.callCurrent(PogoInterceptableSite.java:55)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:51)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:171)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:203)
    at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.applyPathParamsAndSendRequest(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:1653)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:107)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:323)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1262)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1029)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:816)
    at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.invokeMethod(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.call(PogoInterceptableSite.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.callCurrent(PogoInterceptableSite.java:55)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:51)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:171)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:203)
    at restAssure.Test1.main(Test1.java:14)
```

### Jars Added

[image: Jars added]

Comment: Try adding rest-assured-all.jar from [here](https://jar-download.com/artifacts/io.rest-assured).

Comment: okk i will try and let you know

Comment: No change..Same exception

Comment: Mavenise your project

Comment: ... or Gradelize your project.  Or in general: use a build tool to get the set of direct and transitive dependencies for your project, so you don't have to hunt on the internet for jars for each class-not-found exception.

Comment: okk..i will try with maven..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mavenise the project worked for me